# Why do most of the books in mathematics not include answers?

Tags: undergraduate-education, self-learning

I am currently going through the *Topics in Algebra* by I.N. Herstein. The problems are pretty good, but there are no answers. The same is the case with *Mathematical Analysis* by Rudin.

**Why is this?**

Even though some would argue that it robs the question of its charm, sometimes it is necessary to check out the answer just to get confirmation that what you have done is correct. Moreover it becomes necessary in an environment where you study on your own: Even if I have solved an exercise, there is always a doubt regarding the correctness of the process or answer.

Comment: A lot of the time I think this is because the book is used for teaching and if all the answers were there the problems couldn't be assigned by the professor.

Comment: I feel like the answers to the problems in these books are not the important part. For writing proofs is the journey not the destination that's more important.

Comment: I agree that nowadays this is more of a problem. Related discussion here: http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/6/61

Comment: Also asked at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/13346/18398

Comment: It's mostly a commercial decision. Professors prefer if the answers are not given. Of course for self studiers, this is a killer.

Comment: @Person It's hardly a killer given that most of the solutions to the problems can either be out right be found online in solution manuals or can be verified/gained by asking on Math SE or other such sites.

Comment: Beware that giving answers in a book is not so much a way to check one's solution. It helps if you did not find a solution, but solutions are not unique so the book doing it another way does not mean one's solution is wrong; and students are not always able to tell a correct argument from a close but wrong argument so the book doing it mostly in the same way does not mean one's solution is correct.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For a little historical perspective, which at least explains why older books on non-elementary mathematics rarely have "solutions":

Imagine first that there's no internet, that long-distance phone calls are prohibitively expensive, and that photocopying is not only expensive but mostly inaccessible to students. Imagine also that people use the same homework and exam questions over-and-over. The only step needed to prevent gaming the system is to not put solutions in the book (or in the library, either). Done.

In combination with that immobility of information, there was a sort of macho culture of not telling anyone who couldn't *already* do a problem how to do it. This is perverse from an educational or scientific viewpoint, of course, but that doesn't mean that humans won't do it. That is, homeworks and exams would be graded, and points subtracted, and things marked "nonsense", *without* any "approved solution" being given, much less "published".

The common student complaint that they can't tell whether their own "solution/proof/computation" is correct... raises a different point, namely, that students should be very strongly encouraged to develop exactly the sensibilities to know at least roughly whether they're doing the right thing. (The culture of math as rules imposed by an ineffable external authority doesn't help.)

Ignoring that misguided complaint, *my* complaint is that there are many important, useful, traditional questions/issues with essentially no expert-written treatments... because they're always assigned as exercises... but/and crappy very-inexpert solutions or pseudo-solutions or non-solutions *do* circulate, thus misleading, certainly not *helping*, myriad yet-more-junior students.

Thus, by now, given the mobility of information, I think good, that is, "expert", solutions *should* be available. Yes, this does entail that "assessment" methods have to change. So be it. Also, people can read and write.

Comment: I have at least intermittently tried to act on this, including in my on-line algebra notes "worked examples" of all iconic questions, e.g., questions which I'd ask on prelim exams. No secrets... um, considering that it's supposed to be education, not a contest? :)

Comment: I wish I could upvote this a non-countable number of times.

Comment: @Fantini You could always assign a bounty (countable, but shows appreciation).

Comment: I'm sorry but the first part unless meant sarcastically is utter nonsense as really is the end. The reason HW's aren't worked out isn't that there is some secret cabal of professors that doesn't want students to learn things or can't come up with hw/exam questions. The main reason is that many students are too lazy to do the hw and will copy answers if it's easy. Most professors would love not having to grade hw and just assign problems with worked out solutions so students can practice on their own.

Comment: As for exam grading/assessment methods it is trivial to make up problems for exams in general. I've never used problems from the book for exams and the time I spent on making exams was spent balancing the problems properly rather than thinking them up.

Comment: @DRF, I am willing to believe that you've not seen the phenomena I've indicated, but _I_ have been repeatedly yelled-at over the years by "colleagues" for my general impulse to put things on-line, whether calculus or graduate-level stuff. Yes, many students would/do "just copy", but/and while homework does not contribute to grades in my courses, I do go over it and critique writing and content, and return it prior to the exam, as well as making solutions available... which, year-to-year, accumulate, of course. Perhaps I'm somehow living in a "nonsense" world, as sometimes seem to be the case.

Comment: ... and, yes, while I myself do not feel that it's very difficult to come up with homework or exam questions, many of my colleagues claim that it is so. Etc. Also that it is difficult to grade anything. And many other claims, yes, possibly veiling laziness, but, after all, at my R1 uni there's no direct reward for doing any more than the minimum teaching-wise.

Answer (score 8):

In my experience whenever answers are provided a huge majority of students will rush for the answers before even giving it a try. Unfortunately the best you learn from an exercise, especially a non routine one, sits in the gloomy time during which you're trying to figure out what to do and have no clues...

I think giving immediately all solutions to students is enforcing a bad habit. It is a fact that when a problem is difficult it is human to face some form of lazyness. Not providing solutions is a way to stimulate people to overcome this laziness. You do not learn much from reading a solution if you did not REALLY try to solve the problem yourself.

I think it ios for this reason that at times solution are provided in a separate form. Personally (i.e. undergrad level) whenever I put some exercises on line from my students I postpone providing solutions of a certain amount of time...

@paul garrett Nowadays with internet and all the likes gaming the sistem is impossibile due to the mobility of informations... my students are much less proficient than I am in finding solved exercises online.

Comment: Nicola, welcome to the site! I like your answer and look forward to seeing you around more. One small suggestion -- your note to Paul Garrett will not be delivered to him unless you move it from your answer to a comment on his answer. Maybe you already know this, in which case I apologize!