# Why do we state the antiderivative of $\sec x$ as $\ln |\sec x +\tan x|+C$?

Tags: trigonometry, integration

One easy integration of $\sec x$ substitutes $u=\sin x$, viz.$$\int\frac{\cos x}{1-\sin^2 x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}\right|+C.$$Multiplying top and bottom by $1+\sin x$ and writing $1-\sin^2 x=\cos^2 x$ gives the more familiar $$\ln\left|\sec x+\tan x\right|+C.$$A proof written so as to get to that result first requires more elaborate tricks, such as comparing the derivatives of $\sec x$ and $\tan x$ to spot a solution to $y'=y\sec x$, or to use the fact that $f:=\sec x,\,g:=\tan x$ satisfy$$f^2=g^2+1\implies\frac{f'}{g}=\frac{g'}{f}\implies\frac{d}{dx}\ln\left|f+g\right|=\frac{f'}{g}=\sec x.$$So why is the sec/tan formula for an antiderivative universally taught, instead of the sine-based one?

Comment: With suitable limits the integral computes the distance from $(0,0)$ to $(\sec x, 0)$ in the constant curvature $-4$ metric on the unit disk. From this point of view the form in terms of $\sin x$ is more natural than the form in terms of $\sec x$ and $\tan x$.

Comment: @DanFox That's interesting. What is the constant curvature $-4$ metric?

Comment: @J.G.: I just mean a rescaling of the hyperbolic metric. Hopefully I got the constant right.

Comment: My [Bronstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bronshtein_and_Semendyayev) gives $\ln (\tan(x/2 +\pi/4))$ as antiderivative. This comes from the nice antiderivative $\ln (\tan(x/2))$ of $\csc$ by using that $\cos$ is just $\sin$ shifted by $\pi/2$. (It also only uses the function mentioned by @BPP).

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg That form is mainly used when it's important for Mercator projection.

Comment: I guess it was used because it was easier to look up logarithms of tans in tables than to look up sec and tan, add them and then get out a logarithm table.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg That would explain a $\tan$-only preference, but not the $\sec,\,\tan$-over-$\sin$ preference my question is about.

Comment: It is country dependent I think. In USA and Canada, $\sec$ and $\csc$ are part of trigonometry (in high school). In France (and maybe other European countries), they are not. Francophone countries follow the french system.

Comment: I always assumed it was just so that the antiderivative could be written on one line (i.e., without using fractions). I am shocked to learn that it could possibly be for a different reason.

Comment: Honestly, I haven't seen any Hungarian integral table with the integral of the $\sec$ function. But I'm 100% certain that I'd find it in the Hungarian version of the Bronstein, but that's a different story.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the most effective way to introduce/motivate the anti-derivative of $\sec x$?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10425/whats-the-most-effective-way-to-introduce-motivate-the-anti-derivative-of-sec)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First idea: Maybe just because it's easier to memorize the derivatives and antiderivatives of the trig functions this way: $\sin$ always pairs with $\cos$, $\tan$ always pairs with $\sec$, and $\cot$ always pairs with $\csc$. These are the same pairs you already know from the sum/difference of squares formulas too, if your precalculus trig studies included all<sup>*</sup> 6 functions.

You may put the dividing line between "stuff to memorize" and "stuff to re-derive when needed" in a different place, but at least some students have been expected to memorize those 6 derivatives and 6 antiderivatives.

Second idea: if you arrived at $\int \sec x\ dx$ through a trig substitution, then an answer involving $\sec x$ and $\tan x$ will be easier to translate back to the original variable than one with a pair of $\sin x$, since you already figured out what $\sec x$ is, and again, the relationship between $\sec x$ and $\tan x$ is one of those easy difference-of-squares-equals-1 deals.

<sup>*</sup>Sorry, exsecant and haversine.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the sec+tan form is more helpful at the end of a trig sub problem.

Comment: Moral +1 from me.  I think having a simpler formula to remember is in fact the reason for why it is written this way.  Otherwise leaving it in sin form is more intuitive.  IMNSHO.

Comment: Not an answer, but I think it is my duty to post a link to this paper whenever this integral is mentioned:

http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/math1132s10/secantintegral.pdf

Comment: Great article.  I have taken navigation class and yes Mercator projection is great because of rhumb lines.  (However, you usually still plot a series of segments.  Because Great Circle route is not constant bearing.  But approximating the trip with set of segments is fine.  Hard to really steer a Great Circle.)

Comment: @StevenGubkin The above link has died, and if you have an alternative version, I'd love to read the paper.

Comment: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/cms_upload/0025570x15087.di021115.02p0115x.pdf

Answer (score 5):

[Stewart's text](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1285741552) ([link](https://books.google.com/books?id=AcQJAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA320&dq=%22We%20could%20verify%20Formula%201%20by%20differentiating%20the%20right%20side,%20or%20as%20follows%22)) derives the result via:
$$\int \sec x\ dx = \int \sec x \frac{\sec x +\tan x}{\sec x +\tan x}\ dx = \int \frac{\sec^2 x +\sec x \tan x}{\sec x +\tan x}\ dx$$
and then $u=\sec x +\tan x$. I don't think this is any worse than rewriting $\frac{1}{\cos x} = \frac{\cos x}{1-\sin^2x}$, using a $u$-sub, and then partial fractions.

Also, if you take $\sec$ and $\tan$ to be functions in their own right, then $\ln|\sec x+\tan x|$ requires fewer computational steps than $\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}\right|$.

Comment: Stewart's text?

Comment: Most Calculus II textbooks I've seen (in Canada) also use this method.

Comment: Link now provided to Stewart's text. This is a very standard Calculus text in the U.S.

Comment: @Aeryl Ah yes, between Examples 6 & 7 in Sec. 7.2.