# Impact of GPT4 and future AI development on math curricula in schools

Tags: curriculum

At least since pocket calculators were available there is an ongoing debate in math education of how meaningfull it is to continue to teach students how to calculations only using a paper and pencil. At the beginning the discussions were only about arithmetic operations but later (after CAS systems were available) also for example about calculating integrals. Many concluded that those skills are not needed anymore and one need to focus much more on solving complex problems, creative and critical thinking and mathematical modelling. Calculators or CAS were meant as tools to do the "routine" tasks described above.

[As a side note: At least in Germany I got the impression that this idea never really got implemented, because it didn't work to teach the average student complex, creative problem solving skills. Thus it ended up that exams consist of problems that are not more complex than in earlier times, but require less calculating skills thus being effectively easier]

Now, if you look at GPT4, it one sees that computers cannot only do "routine tasks", but also solve mathematical modelling problems or provide new mathematical proofs. See for example [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.12712.pdf) research paper, where for example on page 40 a math olympiad problem was solved by GPT 4.

I know that currently GPT4 makes many errors and is not really reliable. But if the development goes on as fast as in the past years, this will not sooner or later not be a problem anymore.

So assume that GPT x or another AI can reliable solve such "creative" and "complex" math tasks (which are out of reach for the average high school students).

How to reasonable change the math curricula in this scenario? Are there any reasons to continue teaching math as we have done it in the past? If so, how to explain the students that it makes sense to learn those things when AI can do it better and much faster?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to give exercises when students can use ChatGPT](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/26255/how-to-give-exercises-when-students-can-use-chatgpt)

Comment: @Dominique: I don't think that this is a duplicate. The question you linked does not question the contents of the curriculum, but rather asks how to react to the fact that students could try to have their homework "solved" by a chatbot. The present questions seems rather to be about changes to the curriculum itself in respondence to the existence of such (more or less) advanced chatbots.

Comment: While I tended to find the entire ChatGPT hype a bit enervating (in particular that some people seem to confuse "it will certainly become better" with "it will soon be able to do almost everything"), I begin to like the debate more and more: Apparently it makes people ask the really important questions - in this case, I'm under the impression that the underlying problem is in fact: What is actually the purpose of teaching students math in school? In any case, +1 for the question.

Comment: @Dominique: I think Jochen Glueck explained it well, why it is not a duplicate!

Comment: After having read the reactions from Jochen and Julia, I've decided to retract my close vote.

Comment: @JochenGlueck You previously commented on a different question and said: "I think your question raises an important point and the discussion you would like to have would be interesting. However, Stack Exchange is not designed for questions whose main purpose is to start a discussion. For this reason, the help center says: If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. I am thus voting to close as off-topic." I have hard time understanding why the same comment does not apply to this question.

Comment: @JochenGlueck I don't think your comment should apply to this question, but I didn't think it applied to that other question, either.

Comment: @MahdiMajidi-Zolbanin: Thanks for your comment. I responded under your question that you're referring to.

Comment: This is a silly question.  In this scenario, almost all human labor is redundant, and all of society will be reorganized.  It makes no sense to talk about what math education will look like if society will be completely different and math education now has to suit the needs of this completely unknown, hypothetical society.  We're in a scenario where we are asking 'What is the purpose of school?' and need to answer that before asking 'What is the purpose of teaching math in school?'

Answer (score 4):

I think this is an important question. The issue, as I see it, is that for a long time learning mathematics has been promoted based on applications of mathematics. Obviously this approach fails to address the question that you raised, i.e., it cannot convince high-school students why they should learn tasks that AI can do better and faster. But let me ask another question: suppose one day AI can formulate and prove theorems in mathematics better and faster than humans. Are mathematicians going to abandon mathematics? It depends on why they do mathematics. Do mathematicians do mathematics to prove theorems? Some may, but many others do mathematics because they enjoy it. Consequently, it is reasonable to expect that many mathematicians will continue to do mathematics even if AI one day can formulate and prove theorems. One can ask the same question about music. If one day AI can compose music (it already can, to some extent) will humans stop composing music? Not if they enjoy doing it.

The point I am making is that whether the mathematics curricula should change or not is secondary. What should change before that is the way learning mathematics is promoted. If learning mathematics is promoted based on its enjoyability, rather than its applications, then in response to a high-school student who asks why should I learn tasks that AI can do better and faster, one can say because mathematics is enjoyable? Understandably, mathematics cannot suddenly become enjoyable by just telling people that it is enjoyable and a lot of thought and work is needed to make it enjoyable, which may include changing the curriculum.

Comment: I'm hazy on the distinction being made between "prove theorems" and "do mathematics because they enjoy it". E.g., Chair of U. Chicago math department welcoming a new faculty member: "Remember: Our job is proving theorems" (per Krantz, _How to Teach Mathematics_ 3E, Sec. 6.1).

Comment: "suppose one day AI can formulate and prove..." when that happens, formulating and proving theorems will not be part of the job of a mathematicians anymore.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins A mathematical theorem is a true statement about certain mathematical objects. A proof often uses certain tools. So before one can state and prove a mathematical theorem, objects must be defined and tools must be built. When mathematicians defined manifolds, categories, schemes, topological spaces, homotopy groups, etc., they were not proving theorems. Mathematical induction, reduction mod a prime number p, infinite descent, etc., are tools that have been built to be used in proofs. Finally, some mathematicians formulate important conjectures, even though they can't prove it!

Comment: @MichaelBächtold For comparison, AI can play chess. Did humans stop playing chess when computers learned how to play chess? Why do humans still play chess, when computers can beat *most* humans in chess? When we say AI can formulate and prove theorems, I don't think we mean AI is capable of proving *every* mathematical statement. I think at best, AI will become a tough competitor to human mathematicians.

Comment: Perhaps the job of future mathematicians will become to prove theorems that AI *cannot* prove!

Comment: Shure, but how many people have chess playing as a full time job?

Comment: And how many people formulate and prove theorems just for a hobby in their spare time like others play chess?

Comment: -1 This does not seem coherent.

Comment: Maybe our future job will be to give math lessons after school, the way people give piano lessons now.

Comment: Considering the power of GPT-4 in repetitive tasks like code implementations. Maybe mathematicians can now work on making new algorithms that power AI and Computer Science. Maybe instead of gpt4 replacing mathematicians, mathematicians will now replace software engineers to a certain extent. Just a thought